# Variable value being forgotten after loop VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to set up a `Do While` loop in which one part of the loop only executes once. I am effectively trying to define a cell range for one sheet, and then have my loop apply this same cell range to all sheets/workbooks without having to re-specify the range.

Here is what I have so far:

```
isExecuted = False
Do While FileName <> ""
    ' Open a workbook in the folder
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(Folder & "\" & FileName)

        ' Conditional to select range only once
        If Not isExecuted Then

            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a Range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
            Debug.Print (rng.Address)
            MsgBox "The cells selected were " & rng.Address
            isExecuted = True

        End If


    Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range(rng.Address)

' more stuff goes here
```

In debug mode. the first time this loop executes everything works as expected, and I can see that my rng.Address is the cell range specified. However, on the second loop rng.Address becomes `<ObjectRequired>`, and so the rest of the script fails. Any ideas as to how to permanently set rng.Address to the specified cell range?

Comment: Are you closing the wb in "more stuff goes here"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hard to say what the specific problem is without seeing more code, but I would suggest a more concise logic, like instead of this:

```
    If Not isExecuted Then

        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a Range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
        Debug.Print (rng.Address)
        MsgBox "The cells selected were " & rng.Address
        isExecuted = True

    End If
```

Do this:

```
If rng is Nothing Then
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a Range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
End If
```

NB: If you're closing the workbook during the `' more stuff goes here` part, that probably is killing the object reference to the range

> Any ideas as to how to permanently set `rng.Address` to the specified cell range?

Yes, just preserve the `Address` rather than the *object*. Since the `Address` is a string literal, you can retain this in a `String` variable even if the object reference goes out of scope:

```
Dim addr As String
If addr = vbNullString
    addr = Application.InputBox("Select a Range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8).Address
End If
Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range(addr)
```

Comment: This is fantastic- much more concise and solved the problem immediately. P.s. you were right, I was closing the workbook, so thank you for that addendum!

Answer (score 4):

The Problem is, that the Range Object is connected to the First Workbook. So when you close that workbook, the Range Object will be lost.

You need to **Save the Address in an String Variable**, so you can access it on every Loop.

```
    Dim strAddress as String
    isExecuted = False
    Do While FileName <> ""
        ' Open a workbook in the folder
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(Folder & "\" & FileName)

            ' Conditional to select range only once
            If Not isExecuted Then

                Dim rng As Range
                Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a Range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
                Debug.Print (rng.Address)
                MsgBox "The cells selected were " & rng.Address
                strAddress = rng.Address
                isExecuted = True

            End If


        Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range(strAddress )

    ' more stuff goes here
```

Comment: David got there a little before you but yes this is also a viable way to get around the issue!

Comment: "somehow connected" -- `rng` is a property of a worksheet (which is a property of the workbook). It's not magic :) Also, it's not "opening the next workbook" which causes `rng` to go out of scope, it's *closing* the initial workbook that causes the `rng` to be lost. Cheers..

Comment: right solution, though and I made small edit to your answer to clarify the above points.

Comment: @DavidZemens thank you for the Explination. and the edits

Answer (score -3):

You need to declare the variable outside the if statement, better outside the loop. Else you cant access it outside the if/loop statement.

Comment: Wrong. While this is true in other languages (c#, python, etc) it is not true for VBA. Further, OP's question pertains to iteration (so it's within the scope of the `While` loop anyways).